# Best method to center a responsive div horizontally and vertically in a a 100% div

Tags: html, css

How do I horizontally and vertically center a dynamic div in a div with 100% viewport size?

html

```
<div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.outer-div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.inner-div {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3rLRQ/)**

css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

.outer-div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.inner-div {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The important part is

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
```

that will apply to the first parent that has `position: relative` or to `body` if nothing else has it.